# Add a data pop-up to a d3js map

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Am using [Data-Driven Documents](http://d3js.org/) to integrate `JSON` data with `Google maps`. `JavaScript` overlays a circle and label at a station location. [Here is an example.](http://ontomatica.com/public/test/soils_Arizona/index.html)

[Here is `JavaScript` file](http://ontomatica.com/public/test/soils_Arizona/index.js)

[Here is `JSON` file](http://ontomatica.com/public/test/soils_Arizona/index.json)

In addition to the LatLng for the station location, the `JSON` file includes soil chemistry data. Here is an example for station location 24:

  `"24": {
    "latitude": 31.967240000000004,
    "longitude": -111.09028,
    "pH Buffer": 0.0,
    "pH": 7.53,
    "Aluminum": 25.28,
    "Antimonies": 0.32,
    "Arsenic ": 0.08,
    "Barium": 46.27,
    "Beryllium": 0.2,
    "Boron": 0.66,
    "Cadmium": 0.03,
<more>
    "Zinc": 0.15
  },`

The `JSON` file will be updated to encode chemistry data in quotes, together with measurement symbol - (mg/kg).

**How to update `JavaScript` to reveal the chemical information on `mouseover`.**

Would like to achieve the same effect as implemented for [US Congressional Districts](https://github.com/JeffreyBLewis/congressional-district-boundaries/blob/master/Wyoming_103_to_112.geojson) and on [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/05/03/upshot/the-best-and-worst-places-to-grow-up-how-your-area-compares.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&module=second-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news&abt=0002&abg=1).

Both implement pop-up information on `mouseover` (NYT) or `mouseclick` (US Congressional Districts).

In the case of the US Congressional Districts, the map and the pop-up is rendered using a GitHub service. A subset of the information in the `GeoJSON` file is served in the pop-up.

For example: `"properties": {"startcong": "103", "district": "0", "statename": "Wyoming", "endcong": "112", "id": "056103112000"}`

Is revealed in the pop-up table:

```
| startcong | 103             |
| district  | 0               |
| statename | Wyoming         |
| member    | [object Object] |
| endcong   | 112             |
| id        | 056103112000    |
```

Would like to integrate a service similar to the one used by GitHub, but for a stand-alone `HTML + JS` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google maps doesnt provide high flexibility to customize its maps. The examples NYT and US Congressional Districts are not using google maps. NYT is using direct SVG file of USA Albers map.

That said, google maps event handlers can be overriden by disabling them. In map options add disableDoubleClickZoom: true

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.96,  -111.090),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
scrollwheel: false
});
```

Also change overlayLayer to overlayMouseTarget

```
var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget).append("div")
```

And now add a tooltip to circle represented on the map. I prefer to use [d3.tips](http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js)

```
var tip = d3.tip()
              .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
              .offset([+20, -20])
              .html(function(d) {
                console.log(d);
                return "<span style='color:blue'>"+JSON.stringify(d.value)  + "</span>";
              })


// Add a circle.
marker.append("svg:circle")
.attr("r", 4.5)
.attr("cx", padding)
.attr("cy", padding)
.on("mouseover",tip.show)
.on("mouseout", tip.hide)
.call(tip);
```

Comment: there's an error in d3.tip function . It might be because of d.properties.statename Can you place console.log(d) inside like this .html(function(d){console.log(d); return "<span ....</span>"})

Comment: copy paste the code from answer which is now modified. Tell me what is printed in chrome dev tools console tab

Comment: Ok, it still is the same. Try the modified answer (place the tip function before the circle's code )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77025/discussion-between-tejesh95-and-jay-gray).